# How to add list from api to new list?

Tags: flutter, list, api, dart, concatenation

I'm fetching data from API and want to create pagination. I want to append/add data from API each request to my List. Getting error

> The argument type 'List?' can't be assigned to the
> parameter type 'Iterable'

**This is the api Request where I add api response parsed with model to my new List**

```
 List<FeedData>? feedData;
 FeedModel? feeds;

 getFeed(context) async {
    var response = await apiClient.getFeeds(filter);
    feeds = await FeedModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
    if (feeds != null) {
      feedData?.addAll(feeds!.data);  
    }//printed feedData and result is empty
    isLoading = false;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

**Feed Model**

```
class FeedModel {
  List<FeedData> data;

  FeedModel({required this.data});

  factory FeedModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return new FeedModel(
        data: json['data'].isEmpty
            ? []
            : List<dynamic>.from(json['data'])
                .map((i) => FeedData.fromJson(i))
                .toList());
  }
}
```

**API Response**

```
{
"success": true,
"data": [
    {
        "datetime": "2022-08-01 10:19:00",
        "amount": "179.000000",
        "gross": "179.000000",
        "or_number": 9045,
    }]
  }
```

**This is how I currently render the response**

```
ListView.builder(
 itemCount:
 feed.feeds?.data?.length ?? 0,
 itemBuilder: (context, index) {
 final item =
 feed.feeds?.data?[index];
 return FeedCard(feed: item);
 }),
```

Comment: can you add class FeedData ?

Answer (score 0):

2 solutions

if feeds.data is null return iterable <FeedData>

```
//First
if (feeds != null) {
      if (feeds!.data != null) {
        feedData.addAll(feeds!.data!);
      }
    }

//Second
if (feeds != null) {
    feedData.addAll(feeds!.data); 
}
class FeedModel {
  List<FeedData> data;
 // change   List<FeedData>?  data; to   List<FeedData> data;
  FeedModel({required this.data});
// change  FeedModel({this.data}); to   FeedModel({required this.data});


  factory FeedModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return new FeedModel(
        data: json['data'].isEmpty
            ? []
            : List<dynamic>.from(json['data'])
                .map((i) => FeedData.fromJson(i))
                .toList());
  }
}
```

Comment: Used both solutions and feedData is still null. Updated the code